# Can characters join units?

Tags: age-of-sigmar

In Warhammer Fantasy characters could join units to move and fight alongside them. In Age of Sigmar characters have different Warscrolls and there don't appear to be any obvious rules to allow them to do so. Is it possible?

The reason I ask is largely to do with battleshock, obviously if a character is part of a unit suffering battleshock then they have a higher bravery value.

So, in Age of Sigmar can characters join units?

Comment: I appreciate a sigmar tag would be better here but I can't create new tags on the mobile site. If someone can retag please feel free!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First page under Warscrolls & Units heading.

"A unit can have one or more models, but cannot include models that use different warscrolls."

No.  No warscroll may ever join another war scroll.  Characters are always alone and may never join units.  The only exceptions would be if a specific character has an ability on their warscroll that allows them to join another warscroll.  Goblin fanatics (not a character) are the only example I can think of offhand, but they are actually hidden within a unit.

Comment: I don't play Age of Sigmar, but if you down vote, can explain why and give suggestions to improve the answer please?

Comment: Also worth mentioning is war machines and crew... They are generally two warscrolls that mention each other and work together.